# Is living at home into adulthood a modern phenomenon?

Tags: family, children

I'm looking into my family history and one of my ancestors in 1901 was still living at home with his father, mother and younger siblings at age 25 in England.

This is atypical with most of the ancestors I've found so far, as most married very young and left home before they were 20. Was it socially exceptable to live at home with your parents for that long? Id like to know more about whether he may have been a help or a hindrance, bearing in mind he had two younger brothers, one 20 and one 18, that were perfectly capable of looking after his ageing father who was 57.

So to revert to my question was this a kind of freak event or was it common for children to live with their parents as adults in this period of history like it is today (at least in England)?

Comment: @JohnDallman done

Comment: It is my understanding that at least until recently, until married. adult children in Italy would stay at their parents' home. It may be that getting married was the trigger, as would make sense, and what has changed is that many more people are getting married later or not at all. Also, it has become more expensive in the last generation or so to buy or rent. So a combination of factors may make living at home into adulthood a modern phenomenon if indeed it is.

Comment: I think for unmarried women it was very common, unless they went into service, as it was not acceptable for a single woman to live alone until the early 20th century. Even Queen Victoria had to have her mother living with her until she married Albert! With sons it was probably income dependent, as most would have been expected to prepare for a career or undertake an apprenticeship.

Comment: @TheHonRose they were all working men but the family was probably quite low income, all bottom of the ladder working class jobs

Comment: @Charlie then maybe it was cheaper to live at home than pay for very low standard rented accommodation?

Comment: @TheHonRose you're probably right. I'd like to know if this was a common occurrence though as it'll give me an insight into what kind of personality he was.